# Como recorrer todos los bootstrap-table de mi pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui

Buenos dias actualmente tengo una aplicacion .net mvc donde en una vista tengo varias tablas y el objetivo es poder obtener todos los datos de todas las tablas, este es mi codigo html para una de las tablas:

```
<div name="7488" id="7488" control-type="TIssFormTable">
<div class="box">
<div class="box-header">
<div class="bootstrap-table">
<div class="fixed-table-container">
<div class="fixed-table-header"> 
</div>
<div class="fixed-table-body"> 
<div class="fixed-table-loading">Loading, please wait...</div>
<table id="table-7488" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data- 
pagination="true" class="table-hover table-responsive table">
<thead><tr id="column-7488">
<th data-sortable="true" width="350">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">Problem</div>
<div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">None</div>
<div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">Mild</div>
<div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">Moderate</div>
<div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">Severe</div>
<div class="fht-cell">
</div></th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="tbody-7488">
<tr id="value-0-7488">
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">DEPRESSED MOOD</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">R</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">J</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="value-1-7488">
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">MOOD SWINGS</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="value-2-7488">
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">IRRITABILITY</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="value-3-7488">
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">POOR CONCENTRATION</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">t</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="value-4-7488"><td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable- 
7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">AGITATION</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">A</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="value-5-7488">
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">SLEEP DISTURBANCE</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="value-6-7488">
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">FATIGUE/LOW ENERGY</td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
<tfoot>
<tr></tr></tfoot>
</table> <div class="fixed-table-footer"></div> <div class="fixed-table- 
pagination"></div> 
</div></div></div></div></div></div>


<table id="table-7587" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data- 
pagination="true" class="table-hover table-responsive table">
<thead>
<tr id="column-7587">
<th data-sortable="true" width="250">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">Medication</div>
<div class="fht-cell"></div>
</th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">DosageFreq</div>
<div class="fht-cell"></div></th>
<th data-sortable="true" width="50">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">StartDate</div>
<div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="250">
<div class="th-inner sortable both">Purpose</div>
<div class="fht-cell"></div></th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="tbody-7587">
<tr id="value-0-7587">
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7587" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">
</td><td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7587" ''="" 
contenteditable="true">
</td><td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7587" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7587" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="value-1-7587">
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7587" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7587" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7587" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
<td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7587" ''="" 
contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr></tbody><tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot></table>
```

Tengo 2 tablas que tienes datos y otras 4 que en estos momentos no tienen dato cuando pongo el codigo javascript no me toma los datos de las tablas que estan vacias solo me repite los datos de la tabla que tiene elementos.

Y he intentado con esto para probar y no me funciona:

```
$('#table-7488 tr').each(function() {
var field = $(this).find("td:first").html();    
});
```

Comment: Y si remueves el `:first` que pasa?

Comment: le puse first a ver si me daba el primero para ver pues no me da ninguno aunque lo remueva

Answer (score 2):

Podes buscar los td dentro de tu tabla y luego recorrerlos para obtener el valor de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('#table-7488').find("td").each(function() {
  var field = $(this).html();  
  console.log(field);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-7488" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data- pagination="true" class="table-hover table-responsive table">
 <thead>
  <tr id="column-7488">
   <th data-sortable="true" width="350">
   <div class="th-inner sortable both">Problem</div>
   <div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
   <div class="th-inner sortable both">None</div>
   <div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
   <div class="th-inner sortable both">Mild</div>
   <div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
   <div class="th-inner sortable both">Moderate</div>
   <div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-sortable="true" width="50">
   <div class="th-inner sortable both">Severe</div>
   <div class="fht-cell"></div>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tbody-7488">
  <tr id="value-0-7488">
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">DEPRESSED MOOD</td>
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">R</td>
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">J</td>
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true"></td>
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="value-0-7488">
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">DEPRESSED MOOD2</td>
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">R2</td>
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">J2</td>
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">2</td>
   <td class="input-details" data-field="TIssFormTable-7488" ''="" contenteditable="true">2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Saludos!

Comment: ya pude hacerlo pero ahora me genera un problema o sea en mi vista tengo 6 tablas de las cuales 2 de ellas solo tienen datos, entonces me repite los datos por cada tabla vacia, Ayuda!!!

Comment: no me queda del todo claro tu inconveniente, podrias actualizar tu pregunta con el codigo tal como lo tienes ahora. con el html con todas las tablas incluido.

Comment: Hola Leonardo actualice el codigo puse otra tabla sin datos pues lo que pasa es que la que tiene datos, se obtiene los valores bien pero la que no tiene lo que hace es repetirme lo mismo de la tabla que tiene elementos.

Comment: @RaidelFonseca y que codigo utilizas para ver los datos de la otra tabla? agrega eso tambien, en el codigo que te pase a modo de ejemplo tendrias que actualizar el id que tiene esa tabla en particular sino te va a seguir mostrando los datos de la tabla que tiene id "table-7488"